# How to crawl a page using sitespeed.io which require authentication?

Tags: node.js

I was trying to crawl our internal site with depth 2 but failed to get any other pages analysed?

Can you help me, if you did similar thing earlier?

```
sitespeed.io -v -u http://appdomain/login -b firefox -d 2 --basicAuth user:password
```

Result :

```
1 page analyzed for http://appdomain/login
```

Comment: I believe the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module supports authentication.  I'd try using that first.

Comment: I'll try that out, and revert on outcome. Thanks for revert @Josh1billion.